# Как вернуть либо String, либо Object

Tags: java

Есть JSON файл:

```
"Name": "Java"
"Adress" : {
     "type" : "asdad
}
```

Сейчас есть две функции, которые по запросу возвращают либо `String`:

```
return jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();
```

либо `Object`:

```
return jsonObject.get("adress");
```

Можно ли как-нибудь объединить эти две функции в одну?

Comment: Объединить можно (например, чтобы всегда возвращался `Object`), но зачем? Есть метод получения `name`, есть метод получения написанного с ошибкой `address` - зачем их мешать в один метод? Если нужно их всегда вместе передавать - создайте из них единый объект, у которого в качестве полей будут `name` и `address`, и используйте его.

Comment: В address несколько полей (для примера написал один)

Comment: А на что это влияет в плане моего комментария?

Comment: Хорошо. Отвечу по-другому: надо сделать так,как я написал.

Comment: Хотите - объединяйте, право ваше. Пару вариантов я предложил. Из них вариант с возвратом единого объекта звучит куда лучше, чем вариант возврата `Object` с выбором между возвращением `name` и `address` с помощью какого-то флага.